# Wordpress Blog renders poorly in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've read several similar posts but am still at a loss so I'd appreciate some help here.

In Firefox & Chrome the page looks exactly as it should http://www.deductyourhome.com.au/ wheras at the widget, Home Middle 3, the Recent Comments scroll has ridiculously huge font and is and overlaid.

Further down that widget, "Take The Test Now" is too large and the following font is in bold when it shouldn't be and below that, the font under "Contact Us Today" also should not be in bold.

Essentially, this widget should render the same as Home Middle 2 (i.e. the column to the left).

At Home Bottom 1, 2 & 3, all font except headings should not be in bold and the second one is clearly erroneously enormous and overlaid.

Here's the code for Home Middle 3 widget:

```
<!-- home middle 2 -->

<iframe width="290" height="290" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/S4q4mas5aPE?hl=en&fs=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div><h1 align="center" style="line-height: 26px">
A Substantially Tax Deductible Home Improves Your Wealth & Lifestyle!</h1></div>
<div align="justify" style="font-size: medium; color: #333399; font-family: helvetica">
<p>Deduct Your Home provides fresh thinking that's vastly superior in many ways to anything your financial planner, finance broker, stock broker, bank, real estate agent, lawyer &amp; accountant have ever put on the table or could hope to devise and perfect anytime soon!</p>
<p>It shreds debt fast saving you tens to hundreds of thousands in mortgage interest!</p>
<p>It smashes tens of thousands or more from your annual assessable income by legally claiming a huge proportion of your home mortgage interest, council and water rates &amp; building insurance and even lets you claim depreciation on your home!</p>
<p>It sends capital gains tax packing if you later sell your home at a profit (here’s hoping when the time comes)!</p>
<p>It’s often cash-flow positive within mere months leaving the rest of your life to soak it up!</p>

<h1 align="center" style="line-height: 26px">
Checked & Approved By The Authorities!
</h1></div>
<div align="justify" style="font-size: medium; color: #333399; font-family: helvetica">

Our system, products and services have been extensively examined and approved by each of  the Australian Securities and Investment Commission, the Australian Taxation Office &amp; the Tax Practitioners Board to the extent they've respectively confirmed we’re not operating an unlicensed financial services business, promoting illegal tax exploitation schemes or providing unregistered tax agent services!</p>
<p>Furthermore, in response to our correspondence to The Federal Treasurer (in seeking certainty for our clients), we requested that he  discuss our home business proposals with the Federal Commissioner of Taxation and to kindly get back to us with any concerns etc and where we have since been twice informed in writing by his office, that in speaking, the Commissioner said our clients can obtain the Government's protection regarding their tax affairs by way of applying for a private tax ruling as based on our home business proposal. Ladies and gentlemen, this is as good as it gets - period. Accordingly, you can now tap into our exclusive intellectual property (IP), confidential information or know-how (it's all the same thing), to achieve optimum, ultra-safe outcomes on this basis and that noone can compete with or deny.

</p><p>

We further take this opportunity to thank the ATO for respecting our claim of ownership in the IP in NOT having published any details into the public domain as would otherwise normally have occurred under the circumstances in which the relevant taxation officers were made aware. 

</p><p>

Of note, BetterLifePanel®, a related entity of our parent company, is Australia’s sole training provider to progressive accountants, registered tax agents, lawyers and financial planers, regarding proprietary and highly advanced, adviser training and client management systems on these same cutting-edge processes. Accordingly, once we have assisted you to secure your own tax ruling, we can point you towards qualified and suitably trained, professionals to assist you into the future with these and other matters!

</p><p>

The bottom line is we'll help you to obtain written ATO confirmation on your circumstances that the sorts of things we'll discuss with you are true and proper etc!</p>

Now that's safe!

</p>

<h1 align="center" style="line-height: 14px">
Make It Good Debt!
</div>
```

And here's the code for Home Bottom 1 widget:

```
<!-- Home Bottom #1 -->
<div align="justify" style="font-size: medium; color: #333399; font-family: helvetica">
<p>John earns $120,000 p.a in his job.</p>
<p>He lives in a nice home that's worth around $1,000,000 with a mortgage of $600,000 @ say 8% interest (long-term average).</p>
<p>He can likely restructure himself to attain deductions of around $50,000 p.a. that he can use to offset his wage and salary income going forward  thus saving him around $18,500 p.a in tax (medicare levy excluded).</p>
<p>He can also pay no capital gains tax in future should he hopefully sell his property for a profit.</p>
<p>See more examples <a href="http://www.deductyourhome.com.au/examples/">HERE</a></p>
</div>

<!-- Start of StatCounter Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var sc_project=6797160; 
var sc_invisible=0; 
var sc_security="c52d8549"; 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"></script><noscript><div
class="statcounter"><a title="wordpress visitor"
href="http://statcounter.com/wordpress.com/"
target="_blank"><img class="statcounter"
src="http://c.statcounter.com/6797160/0/c52d8549/0/"
alt="wordpress visitor" ></a></div></noscript>
<!-- End of StatCounter Code -->
```

And here's the code for Home Bottom 3 widget:

```
<!-- Home Bottom #1 -->
<div align="justify" style="font-size: medium; color: #333399; font-family: helvetica">
<p>“Imagination is everything. It is the preview of life's coming attractions". ~Albert Einstein.</p>

</br>

"Some people get lost in thought because it's such unfamiliar territory".  ~G. Behn.</p>

</br>

"No problem can withstand the assault of sustained thinking".  ~Voltaire.</p>

</br>


"Too often we enjoy the comfort of opinion without the discomfort of thought".  ~John F. Kennedy.</p>

</br>

"Thinking is the hardest work there is which is probably the reason so few engage in it". ~ Henry Ford. 

</div>
```

Comment: I am seeing "magic" quotes on here `“Imagination is everything`. You should make sure your code is using HTML entities if you really want things like that, The fact they're mixed in with regular quotes indicates you need to carefully proof your pages, and code before asking others to do it for you.

Comment: posting your style sheet would help a lot

Comment: I'd recommend you remove your email address.

Comment: needs to go to wordpress.stackexchange ?

Comment: In `BetterLifePanel®, a related entity of our parent company, is Australia’s` the `®` and `’` should be `&reg;` and `&#8217` respectively.  As for the `“` that should be `&#147;`

Comment: @FiveTools - http://www.deductyourhome.com.au/wp-content/themes/enterprise/dyh-style.css Frank's CSS is here.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Take the Test** title does not have a font-size specified for the h1 tag so it just uses whatever the browser default is. Try specifying default font sizes for all your h tags. This may fix your other problems too. You specify one for h1.content, but the widget is outside the content area I believe.